# Testing responsive design with poltergeist (phantomjs)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, phantomjs, poltergeist

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and poltergeist. I'm trying to hide some elements for mobile resolutions, for example:

view:

```
<th class="hidden-phone">Email</th> ....
```

css:

```
.hidden-phone {
  display: none !important;
}
```

spec:

```
context 'Phone', js: true do
  it 'should hide some elements' do
    page.driver.resize 320, 480
    visit my_path

    within '#members_list thead tr' do
      expect(page).not_to have_content 'Email'
    end
  end
end
```

but test doesn't pass:

```
Failure/Error: expect(page).not_to have_content 'Email'
   expected content "Email" not to return anything
```

What may be wrong ? When I make screen dump with page.driver.render element is hidden.

Comment: Can you try this: http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_no_text%3F-instance_method

Answer (score 1):

The default options of `have_content` method will look for all text, ignoring hided content.

Try

```
expect(page).not_to have_content(:visible, 'Email')
```

Documentation here http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_text%3F-instance_method

Answer (score 0):

My guess from your example is that the element is being hiding using javascript or some asynchronous behaviour, so when the assert is being evaluated it might be still visible.

In order for it to wait for the element to become hidden or not visible, you can use the build in Capybara API (I'm assuming that you are using Capybara) that provides good support for asynchronous behaviour. So instead of using the assert:

```
expect(page).not_to have_content 'Email'
```

you can use:

```
page.should_not have_selector("#members_list thead tr", :text => "Email")
```

or:

```
page.find("#members_list thead tr").should_not have_content("Email")
```

Just check that the CSS selector is according to the element that you are evaluating.

For more explanation about how these two constructions works or behave, here are the references:
[Capybara - Asynchronous JavaScript (Ajax and friends)](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara)
[Why wait_until was removed from Capybara](http://www.elabs.se/blog/53-why-wait_until-was-removed-from-capybara)

And if it takes to much time for the elements to become hidden given that they wait for a slow AJAX request, you can increase the wait time in `Capybara` before it gives a `TimeOutError` by specifying the following in the `spec_helper.rb` file:

```
Capybara.default_wait_time = 30
```

And also to the `poltergeist` driver to wait more time before give timeout:

```
Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, { timeout: 40 }
```